# Simultaneously checking for multiple substrings using list comprehension

Tags: python, string, substring

Suppose I start with a list of strings:

```
list1 = ['string a','string b','string c','string d']
```

Using list comprehension, I want to create a second list (`list2`) that contains strings from `list1` if and only if those strings contain certain substrings.

For example, if I wanted to pull only the strings containing `'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'`, I could write:

```
list2 = [text for text in list1 if 'a' in text or 'b' in text or 'c' in text]
```

but this feels clunky. Is there a way to combine my search for the three elements, something like... `if ('a' or 'b' or 'c') in text`?

If possible, I would like to do this without having to create a list of the substrings, i.e. `['a','b','c']` in a preceding line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
list1 = ['string a','string b','string c','string d']
list2 = [text for text in list1 if any(k in text for k in ['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```

**Output** :

```
['string a', 'string b', 'string c']
```

Another sample case :

```
list1 = ['string a','string b','string c','string d', 'string e']
list2 = [i for i in list1 if any(k in i for k in ['a', 'd'])]
# ['string a', 'string d']
```

**Note** : You can't do `if ('a' or 'b' or 'c') in text` because `('a' or 'b' or 'c')` is always going to produce `'a'` and you would end up eventually checking `if 'a' in text`.

Check out [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) from documentation.

**Additional Note** : Even though this process require neither declaring any list before hand into a variable nor a cumbersome process of multiple `or` commands inside the `if` condition, your way is still way faster compared to this, specifically if your check list of characters is big. Consider this :

```
>>> from timeit import timeit as t
>>> t("""list1 = ['string a','string b','string c','string d']; list2 = [text for text in list1 if any(k in text for k in ['a', 'b', 'c'])]""")
2.8938145910001367
>>> t("""list1 = ['string a','string b','string c','string d']; list2 = [text for text in list1 if 'a' in text or 'b' in text or 'c' in text]""")
0.600998255000377
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the code inside the any() function is a generator expression, correct?

Comment: @hseek Yes, that's a generator expression. Another variation you could use is make it into a list comprehension and apply `any()` on it like `any([k in i for k in ['a', 'd']])` which should be slightly slower compared to generator expression.